# How can I grab information in MySQL via 2 foreign keys going to the same table?

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I have a table called `sales` with two columns `vendor_id` and `customer_id`. Both are `id`'s to a row in the `people` table. I want to grab a `sales` row by it's `id` and get the `customer` name and the `vendor` name.

How can I do this with MySQL?

Comment: You could use a JOIN statement http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Join your `people` table twice to the `sales` table (you'll need to alias it at least one time in order to avoid a name collision):

```
SELECT customer.name AS customer_name, vendor.name AS vendor_name
FROM   sales
  JOIN people AS customer ON customer.id = sales.customer_id
  JOIN people AS vendor   ON   vendor.id = sales.vendor_id
WHERE  sales.id = ?
```